# PHP application (client) for managing my multiple email accounts

Tags: email, php

Looking for PHP application which I could use on web server instead of Thunderbird to manage my multiple email accounts* (consolidate them like in GMail).

The problem is that I need web-based solution so I could access my accounts from many places :)

* ~8 different accounts and counting :) Why so much? More than half of them are like "support@somesite.com" - for customer support and things like that, so ability to easily change between e-mail accounts is a *must*.

Comment: Any reason you are against gmail doing it?

Comment: Because GMail is run by Google, and I wouldn't trust them.

Comment: @Josh K, seriously? Tin Foil hat much?

Comment: There's a limit to how much I will let Google handle. They are in the business of searching and compiling data. The more you give them the more they have and honestly it's scary what could be done with the amount of data Google sees on a daily basis.

Comment: Yep, I do not do anything harmful or illegal and I am not paranoid about Google, but I do not trust them that much, that I could let them handle all my accounts.

Comment: Also Gmail does not support more than 5 additional email accounts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a PHP based webmail interface that you can host, have you tried taking a look at [Roundcube](http://roundcube.net/)?

It's AJAX enabled along with other bells and whistles that have always made it appealing when I've considered running my own hosted webmail for my accounts.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I found that yesterday night on the net, but on the first sight I thought it does not have multi-account capability (and I was too tiret to try it :))

Comment: Sorry, but it does not seem to have ability to work with multiple email accounts using one user

Comment: What about running fetchmail to grab your mail from multiple accounts?  Or something similar.  Perhaps check their forums to see if anyone has setup multiple accounts in any way?

Comment: Problem is that, I some times need to access my emails via public computers, also I dual-boot Linux<->Windows (and Thunderbird profile sync via Dropbox gets annoying a lot of times, because I forget to close thunderbird and let Db do the sync).

I've found NOCC which would fit my needs but the problem it requires dynamic extension loading which is not very popular feature in shared hostings :)